# Structure of if/else if statements and php operators confusion

Tags: php

I hate to ask such a tedious question but I'm having trouble structuring my if else statement. I know it's not executing properly because it only gives me the first echo as my answer. I don't really understand && operators in php, I've only just started this language a few days ago. I feel my code should work but it's definitely not so I'm messing up.

If I try isset before the get method I get an error message saying to use null instead.

I tried changing operators to || but that's not really what I'm looking for with the statements. I also tried != but I'm probably structuring the syntax wrong.

```
    <?php
        $power = "";

        if (isset($_GET['power']) < '0.0') 
        {
          echo "Po eats too much noodle";
        } 
        else if (isset($_GET['power']) <= '20.0') 
        {
          echo "Po reaches the training hall";
        } 
        else if (isset($_GET['power']) >= '21.0' && isset($_GET['power']) <= '40.0') 
        {
          echo "Po reaches the student barracks";
        } 
        else if (isset($_GET['power']) >= '41.0' && isset($_GET['power']) <= '60.0') 
        {
          echo "Po reaches the Peach Tree of Heavenly Wisdom";
        } 
        else if (isset($_GET['power']) >= '61.0' && isset($_GET['power']) <= '80.0') 
        {
          echo "Po climbs the Wu Da Mountains";
        } 
        else if (isset($_GET['power']) >= '81.0' && isset($_GET['power']) <= '100.0') 
        {
          echo "Po trains at the Pool of Sacred Tears";
        } 
        else 
        {
          echo "Po defeats Tai Lung";
        } 
     ?>
```

Thank you to anyone who helps!

```
<?php
    $power = "";

    if ($power = ($_GET['power'] < 0.0)) 
    {
      echo "Po eats too much noodle";
    } 
    else if ($power = $_GET['power'] <= 20.0) 
    {
      echo "Po reaches the training hall";
    } 
    else if (($power = $_GET['power'] >= 21.0) && ($power = $_GET['power'] <= 40.0)) 
    {
      echo "Po reaches the student barracks";
    } 
    else if (($power = $_GET['power'] >= 41.0) == ($power = $_GET['power'] <= 60.0))
    {
      echo "Po reaches the Peach Tree of Heavenly Wisdom";
    } 
    else if (($power = $_GET['power'] >= 61.0) || ($power = $_GET['power'] <= 80.0)) 
    {
      echo "Po climbs the Wu Da Mountains";
    } 
    else if (($power = $_GET['power'] > 80.0) && ($power = $_GET['power'] < 100.0)) 
    {
      echo "Po trains at the Pool of Sacred Tears";
    } 
    else 
    {
      echo "Po defeats Tai Lung";
    } 
 ?>
```

This is what I updated. Thank you :) I hope I'm doing the structure right? I can get it to go through now however it won't execute the last two parts. Somehow messing with the operators helped but also didn't help.

Comment: You appear to be doing a lot of comparisons with strings. I would use numbers

Comment: `isset()` returns true\false not the value of the variable

Comment: I would use `$power = $_GET['power'] ?? -1;` and do your comparisons against `$power`

Comment: Oh okay, I used isset to fix an error I was getting with another php document and that worked so I just used it too much here I think. I will try using the structure you mentioned Phil. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You need to learn about code refactoring. You can simply extract `$_GET['power']` to a variable and work with that.

To answer your question `&&` in PHP is similar to the `&&` in most programming languages like Java/C. It just used to check wether both the conditions are evaluated to true.

I see another problem in your code, Looks like `$power` is a floating value. So I have converted it to a float from string. Also you are missing out values like 20.5, 40.5 .. etc on the condition when you do the comparison. Check out the shared code.

```
<?php
$power = floatval($_GET['power']);

if ($power < 0.0) {
    echo "Po eats too much noodle";
} else if ($power <= 20.0) {
    echo "Po reaches the training hall";
} else if ($power <= 40.0) {
    echo "Po reaches the student barracks";
} else if ($power <= 60.0) {
    echo "Po reaches the Peach Tree of Heavenly Wisdom";
} else if ($power <= 80.0) {
    echo "Po climbs the Wu Da Mountains";
} else if ($power < 100.0) {
    echo "Po trains at the Pool of Sacred Tears";
} else {
    echo "Po defeats Tai Lung";
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh, wow that's so much easier looking. I'll remember to do GET on a variable. So I didn't really need the && operator then and I was making it too hard. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This code will work

```
<?php
    $power = $_GET['power'];
    if ($power < 0.0) 
    {
      echo "Po eats too much noodle";
    } 
    else if($power <= 20.0) 
    {
      echo "Po reaches the training hall";
    } 
    else if (($power >= 21.0) && ($power <= 40.0)) 
    {
      echo "Po reaches the student barracks";
    } 
    else if (($power >= 41.0) && ($power <= 60.0)) 
    {
      echo "Po reaches the Peach Tree of Heavenly Wisdom";
    } 
    else if (($power >= 61.0) && ($power <= 80.0)) 
    {
      echo "Po climbs the Wu Da Mountains";
    } 
    else if (($power >= 81.0) && ($power <= 100.0)) 
    {
      echo "Po trains at the Pool of Sacred Tears";
    } 
    else 
    {
      echo "Po defeats Tai Lung";
    } 
 ?>
```